# Org file created on Windows machine. Incorrect open in Linux machine

Tags: org-mode

Emacs 26

On Windows 10 machine create any org file.

[image]

Nice.
Now on Linux Mint try to open same org file.

Here result:

[image]

Why not correct open org file?

Comment: Based on what's visible on the Linux screenshot, it looks like it might perhaps be a Google drive error (it seems as if the HTML "title" might be something like "Sorry...", which might mean that it's an error response from Google drive). That's obviously speculation, but I don't think it's an Org Mode issue.

Comment: @aplaice I success open org file by Nemo (built-in file manager in Linux Mint). But by emacs same org file not correct  open